# VB.NET Export DataGridView to Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, export

I am getting an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" when i try to export a DataGridView to Excel.

I have pasted my code below;

Not quite sure where the error is occurring, any help will be massively appreciated.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Public Property MetroGrid1 As Object

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ValidFromDate.Font = New Font(ValidFromDate.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        ValidFromDate.Text = "Valid From:" & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM,yyyy") & " @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
        Me.Vw_Barcode_CheckTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InfoDataSet.vw_Barcode_Check)

    Private Sub ExportToExcelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportToExcelBtn.Click
        ExportToExcel()
        Dim DateLastRun As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        LastExport.Text = DateTime.Now
        My.Settings.LastRunDate = LastExport.Text
    End Sub
    Private Sub ExportToExcel()
        ' Creating a Excel object.
        Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

        Try

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

            worksheet.Name = "Barcodes"

            Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
            Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

            'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
            For i As Integer = 0 To MetroGrid1.Rows.Count - 2
                For j As Integer = 0 To MetroGrid1.Columns.Count - 1
                    ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                    If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                        worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = MetroGrid1.Columns(j).HeaderText
                    Else
                        worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = MetroGrid1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                    End If
                    cellColumnIndex += 1
                Next
                cellColumnIndex = 1
                cellRowIndex += 1
            Next


            'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
            Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog With {
                .Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                .FilterIndex = 2
            }

            If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
                MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            excel.Quit()
            workbook = Nothing
            excel = Nothing
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are in the best position to determine where the problem is; when the error occurs press Break or Debug and it will take you to the line. Which line is it? Added: remove or comment out the Try/Catch to assist in debugging.

Comment: @AndyG apparently I am missing some symbols. When i use a breakpoint it errors with a missing *.vb symbol file... I will recitify this and see what happens.

Comment: @AndyG The error is on line 48 "For i As Integer = 0 To MetroGrid1.Rows.count - 2"

Comment: `Public Property MetroGrid1 As Object` - First why `Object` and the subsequent late-binding. Second, where is this property assigned a value?

Comment: @TnTinMn Set to Object because VB suggested it as a fix, and second im not sure?

Comment: MetroGrid1 is an object reference, it can refer to some object - but you haven't pointed it to (referenced) any object... It most likely shouldn't be an `Object` anyway.

Comment: @AndyG, i have been programming for little over a month. Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance :)  EDIT: When i remove the MetroGrid1 line 49 errors where i specify the rows.count

Comment: " i have been programming for little over a month." - This is hardly the type of programming that one finds in _intro to programming_ classes, at least not in the first few weeks.

Comment: @TnTinMn i do it to help out mostly, there is a dedicated Developer in my workplace. This is just a side project and i usually ask him for assistance but he isn't here today.

Comment: Presumably MetroGrid1 should be a DataGridView, and there should be code somewhere to set it to the required grid before the code you have shown.

Comment: Fixed it, for starters I didn't need the object reference at all, what i did need was to reference the correct DGV. Where i had "MetroGrid1" it was actually meant to be "NewMetroGrid1" . Fresh perspective on a Monday was helpful. Thanks all :) .